# Getting a subcomponent in tests

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to write a test for a component that contains a `material-checkbox`. I created a page object using the `pageloader` library and I get the reference to the `PageLoaderElement` for the `material-checkbox` using `@ByTagName('material-checkbox')`.

How do I test the `checked` property of the checkbox? I tried accessing the `attributes` and `properties` but they return null for `'checked'`.

Answer (score 0):

`material-checkbox` doesn't set a `checked` attribute; however, it does set `aria-checked="true"` which you could test.